# Tab Indexing issue

Tags: c#, winforms, tabindex

Could please anyone help me to get Tab Index working on my win form.

I have tried all the possibilities (Manual indexing and also through View > Tab Order) but no difference. I have around 35 controls on my form including Text boxes, Drop down boxes and Date time pickers.

It only work when I tab from a drop down box, it moves to the next text box but nothing else happening afterwards.

Though people have posted so many answers to the similar question but I haven't come across to one which explain how to get it work at first place. Mostly people are asking that either their tab index is partially working partially or in doing it in a strange order.

Anyone's help will really be appreciated.

Kind Regards

Comment: Could you post an example source code which replicates this error?

Comment: I am sorry i dont have any source code as I am implementing it through designer

Comment: You still have source code regardless, the designer generates it. Can you create a "Hello World" type application which implements tabbing?

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the same error in my test application with fewer text box controls

Comment: I created a new test application and copied pasted all the controls as it is from my live application. Strangely tabbing works fine with my test application.

Answer (score 1):

Each control on form which should have Tabbing enabled must be filled with this property values:

```
TabStop = true; 
TabIndex = number; //order of indexes
```

Otherwise you should check your tab stops by choosing show Tab Order on designer by choosing - MS Visual Studio => Edit => Tab Order. After this you can click on each component on form in order you want Tabbing in final application.